# Use appropriate identities to find sin (theta) and cos(theta) if tan(theta) = 0.4 and the terminal side of (theta) lies in quadrant III.

Tags: trigonometry

Use appropriate identities to find $\sin (\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ if $\tan(\theta) = 0.4$ and the terminal side of $(\theta)$ lies in quadrant III.

---

sin(theta) =

cos(theta) =

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: One identity that you'll need is $$\bigg(\text{Opposite}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\text{Adjacent}\bigg)^2 = \bigg(\text{Hypotenuse}\bigg)^2$$